# Windows IOT with RPi3 not able to boot after timezone change

Tags: windowsiot, raspberry-pi3

I'm facing some issues with my new RPi3, and using Windows 10 IOT (Build Number 14322). It seems that after I change the default timezone the device won't start over again.

I get a black screen, and the act led flashes 7 times..

Anyone else with similar problems, and know how to fix it?

Comment: is this by changing the date/time in Powershell?

Comment: @Werdna, I tried both via powershell, and with GUI. I have succesfully changed it once via GUI, but the next day I wasnt able to boot.. So something seems off.. If I format my SD card and do a clean install it works as it's supposed.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling IoT?

Comment: @Werdna, Yes, as mentioned above it works after reinstalling.. This is probably my fifth or sixth time reinstalling after various problems..

Comment: ok, i found this link, i dont know if it will be much help to you but there is an insider version of IoT that you can possibly try?
https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/Downloads.htm

Comment: I'm using insider preview 143222. Tested also with the previous one 14292 or something.. When I search on the net most it says that 7 flashes in missing kernel.img but that's not the problem in my case.. I guess some files gets corrupted or something..

Comment: Ok with all that said, i would try raspbian and change the time zone on another operating system, and then see if it fails like in IoT, if it does fail, there could be a hardware issue, however if it doesn't and works as it should for the next couple of days, i would say its a Microsoft issue they are still fixing as the pi3 was not too long ago released.

Comment: @ffffff01 Does this happen even if you change the time with Powershell?